# How do I zoom into a specific object

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, zooming, iboutlet

I am creating an app where when a user taps on a button (an object in the room), I would like the UIViewController to zoom closer to that button upon an IBAction. I would like this to be similar to the pinch zoom but when the user taps on a button.

Help on this would be much appreciated as I cannot find much on the internet, it just comes up with 'can't drag and drop in Xcode while zooming' etc.

Comment: Use a `UIScrollView`. Search on using the zoom features of `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Yes but I do not want the user to be able to pinch zoom

Comment: what about the basic `CGAffineTransform`?

Comment: @holex turn that into a question and I will mark up and accept

Comment: @OnkaPlonka, I just did it, I'm glad if that idea helped on you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I were you, I would really consider to use `CGAffineTransform` to achieve that custom zoom effect. you will find more about the *Quartz2D* programming in the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066).

that would my idea / suggestion for you.